# Create something similar to the iPhone camera functions selector in Codename One

Tags: codenameone

In this picture, there is a screenshot of the iPhone camera functions selector: the user can horizontally scroll them, and the function name moved to center is selected (it changes its color and it calls a listener that activate the function). It's easier to test on a real iPhone than to describe.

The behavior is very similar to the lightweight string picker, but the main differences are that it's horizontal and it's always shown (while the string picker can be opened and closed).

At the moment, I haven't no idea how to replicate it in Codename One: I need to put it over a camera PeerComponent. I need something "enough" similar and usable: the rotating effect (that I suppose hard to replicate) is very nice but not strictly necessary.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the one case where `List` has no better substitute. Notice that this doesn't cover the slight 3d effect in iOS. You can fake it a bit by using a layered layout and gradient fade on top of the list but that might not look great:

```
Form f = new Form("Horizontal List", new BorderLayout());

DefaultListCellRenderer.setShowNumbersDefault(false);    com.codename1.ui.List<String> l = new com.codename1.ui.List<>("Time-Lapse", "Slo-Mo", "Video", "Foto", "Ritrato");

l.setOrientation(com.codename1.ui.List.HORIZONTAL);
l.setFixedSelection(com.codename1.ui.List.FIXED_CENTER);

f.add(SOUTH, l);

f.show();
```

[image]