# Carousel with thumbnail images at the bottom

Tags: codenameone

In a Codenameone app, I'm trying to develop a carousel with a thumbnail list at the bottom. I've used Tabs control to display files (of diff types like images, video, text, button etc) in carousel style in the center of a form and another Tabs control to display thumbanail images (of the first carousel files) at the bottom of the form. When a user selects a thumbnail image in the bottom carousel, corresponding component should be displayed in the first carousel.

```
hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, mainCarousel);
hi.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, bottom_tab);

bottom_tab.addSelectionListener((i1, i2) -> {            
       // bottom_tab.getTabComponentAt(i2).addPointerPressedListener((i) -> {
            mainCarousel.getTabComponentAt(i2).setVisible(true);
            mainCarousel.getTabComponentAt(i2).repaint();
       // });            
    });
```

But the component not getting displayed in the central carousel.
Also, I tried to capture the event addPointerPressedListener, but it's not getting fired when I select a thumbnail image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't set tab components to visible/invisible to show/hide them. That won't work. I'm guessing that what you want is a horizontal list for the bottom UI similar to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53383954/create-something-similar-to-the-iphone-camera-functions-selector-in-codename-one/53386684).

I would suggest using pointer released always. Notice that this will only get delivered to focusable components or the form. To make sure you get the event you can register a pointer release listener on the form.

Comment: I could select a tab component to be shown using mainCarousel.setSelectedIndex(iIndex, true);  But now the question is how do I get the selected component index.

Comment: I've added a sample screenshot of the app. There are two carousels. When I select an image from the bottom Tab/Container, corresponding image/video would be displayed in the center carousel. I've used Tabs for the center carousel and a Container for the bottom one. Regarding display of selected Image in the center carousel, I can use mainCarousel.setSelectedIndex(iIndex, true);  But now I'm not able to get the selected image index on the bottom container using PointerPressed event. How can I achieve it?

Comment: There are two approaches you can take. First actually use the tabs rather than two separate tabs which totally won't work here. Just set the tabs to thumbnail images with no text. The second option is to use the horizontal list with images as I explained in the sample I liked in the answer. List has an action listener which can let you know an entry was selected and tabs have a selection listener too.

Comment: Thanks Shai. The second option sounds good to me. But I'm not sure how do I add Images to the List? Should I implement ListModel then how to get the selected index....

Comment: You can use DefaultListModel list has a selected index. I suggest checking out the sample I listed, just place the list in the south instead of using a layered layout

Comment: I used DefaultModelList as follows                                     DefaultListModel<Map<String, Object>> model = null;                                          ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> data = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
InputStream is = Display.getInstance().getResourceAsStream(getClass(), "/Apr"+i+".jpg");
Image img = Image.createImage(is).scaled(70, 70); 
Map<String, Object> entry = new HashMap<>();
entry.put("Line1", "Tab"+i);
entry.put("icon", img);
data.add(entry);
model = new DefaultListModel<>(data);ml = new MultiList(model);

Comment: I'm little confued about how to get the selected index. I added selection listener but it doesn't give me selected index..                                              ml.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {
                @Override
                public void selectionChanged(int oldSelected, int newSelected) {
                    Log.p(" old "+oldSelected+" new "+newSelected);   
                }
            });

Comment: I got it                                                                                                                            ml.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    MultiList selectedMl = (MultiList)evt.getActualComponent();
                    int iTabIndx = selectedMl.getSelectedIndex();
                    Log.p(" >> "+iTabIndx);
                    t.setSelectedIndex(iTabIndx, true);
                }
            });