# Show selected image in ImageViewer

Tags: codenameone

This question is related to my other question at [Carousel with thumbnail images at the bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53705492/carousel-with-thumbnail-images-at-the-bottom)
I'm trying to implement a similar carousel but only of Images, using ImageViewer and DefaultListModel. When I select a thumbnail image from the bottom carousel, I show corresponding image in the ImageViewer. But what I noticed is that; the list in the ImageViewer doesn't get scrolled to the selected image but the currently displayed image gets replaced with the selected one. The  So when I swipe to left or right; the images are different than the original sequence. Following is my code to show the selected image in Imageviewer

**imageviewer.setImage(imageviewer.getImageList().getItemAt(selectedImgIndx));**

Is there any way to make it behave like a Tab.setSelectedIndex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, use:

```
imageviewer.getImageList().setSelectedIndex(idx);
```